# How to determinate edge-to-edge enabled?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fullscreen, statusbar, edge-to-edge

How to determine in my fragment that in activity enabled edge-to-edge with function
`WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)`

Any ideas?

Is it possible to get the value of `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)`?

Answer (score 1):

There's no public API to query this state. You might need to manage this state in your app, perhaps by setting a flag when you enable edge-to-edge and then checking that flag in your fragment instead?

Alternatively you might try to deduct that from system UI visibility flags:

```kotlin
val isEdgeToEdgeEnabled = activity?.window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility?.and(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION) != 0
```

But that would require use of reflection which can be risky because it might not work across different Android versions or devices and can break in future Android updates, so I do not recommend going that way if use of own flag suffices.

Comment: activity?.window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility?.and(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION) != 0 returns false ... most likely I will have to store a variable in an activity with a state and wait for the public API :) Thanks for the quick advice